# Is there a way to scrape ads' url from SeLoger?

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape the french website SeLoger, I can find and scrape all ads and put it in an Json.
The issues is I can't find the final url of the ads with this way.
The Url is in a div called "cartouche" with the class c-pa-link link_AB.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json


url = 'https://www.seloger.com/list.htm?tri=initial&enterprise=0&idtypebien=2,1&idtt=2,5&naturebien=1,2,4&ci=440109'
headers = {
    'User-Agent': '*',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1'
    }


s = requests.Session()
s.headers.update(headers)

r = s.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

for script_item in soup.find_all('script'):
    if 'var ava_data' in script_item.text:
        raw_json = script_item.text.split('var ava_data = ')[1].split('};')[0] + "}"


data = json.loads(raw_json)

print(data)
```

I expected to put a field in the json like this.

```
{
            "url":"https://www.seloger.com/annonces/achat/appartement/nantes-44/centre-ville/144279775.htm?enterprise=0&natures=1,4&places=%5b%7bci%3a440109%7d%5d&projects=2,5&qsversion=1.0&types=1,2&bd=ListToDetail",
            "idannonce": "149546457",
            "idagence": "294918",
            "idtiers": "323172",
            "typedebien": "Appartement",
            "typedetransaction": [
                "viager"
            ],
            "idtypepublicationsourcecouplage": "SL",
            "position": "2",
            "codepostal": "44100",
            "ville": "Nantes",
            "departement": "Loire-Atlantique",
            "codeinsee": "440109",
            "produitsvisibilite": "AD:AC:BX:AW",
            "affichagetype": [
                {
                    "name": "liste",
                    "value": "True"
                }
            ],
            "cp": "44100",
            "etage": "0",
            "idtypechauffage": "0",
            "idtypecommerce": "0",
            "idtypecuisine": "séparée équipée",
            "naturebien": "1",
            "si_balcon": "1",
            "nb_chambres": "1",
            "nb_pieces": "2",
            "si_sdbain": "0",
            "si_sdEau": "0",
            "nb_photos": "15",
            "prix": "32180",
            "surface": "41"
        }
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `zip()` functions to "tie" products from json data to URLs in the webpage:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

url = 'https://www.seloger.com/list.htm?tri=initial&enterprise=0&idtypebien=2,1&idtt=2,5&naturebien=1,2,4&ci=440109'
headers = {
    'User-Agent': '*',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1'
    }

s = requests.Session()
s.headers.update(headers)

r = s.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

for script_item in soup.find_all('script'):
    if 'var ava_data' in script_item.text:
        raw_json = script_item.text.split('var ava_data = ')[1].split('};')[0] + "}"

data = json.loads(raw_json)

for a, p in zip(soup.select('.c-pa-info > a'), data['products']):
    p['url'] = a['href']

print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
```

Prints:

```
...

{
    "idannonce": "139994713",
    "idagence": "48074",
    "idtiers": "24082",
    "typedebien": "Appartement",
    "typedetransaction": [
        "vente"
    ],
    "idtypepublicationsourcecouplage": "SL9",
    "position": "16",
    "codepostal": "44000",
    "ville": "Nantes",
    "departement": "Loire-Atlantique",
    "codeinsee": "440109",
    "produitsvisibilite": "AM:AC:BB:BX:AW",
    "affichagetype": [
        {
            "name": "liste",
            "value": true
        }
    ],
    "cp": "44000",
    "etage": "0",
    "idtypechauffage": "0",
    "idtypecommerce": "0",
    "idtypecuisine": "0",
    "naturebien": "2",
    "si_balcon": "0",
    "nb_chambres": "0",
    "nb_pieces": "3",
    "si_sdbain": "0",
    "si_sdEau": "0",
    "nb_photos": "4",
    "prix": "147900",
    "surface": "63",
    "url": "https://www.selogerneuf.com/annonces/achat/appartement/nantes-44/139994713/#?cmp=INTSL_ListToDetail"
},
{
    "idannonce": "146486955",
    "idagence": "334754",

...
```

NOTE: Some URLs have different structure from

```
https://www.seloger.com/annonces/achat/appartement/nantes-44/centre-ville/{idannonce}.htm?ci=440109&enterprise=0&idtt=2,5&idtypebien=2,1&naturebien=1,2,4&tri=initial&bd=ListToDetail
```

for example

```
https://www.selogerneuf.com/annonces/investissement/appartement/nantes-44/146486955/#?cmp=INTSL_ListToDetail
```

Comment: Thank you Andrej, I will try when I came back home :)